# C# Web Browser infinite loading loop

Tags: c#, loops, browser

I'm working on a web scraper, and I have the actual loading of the page and sorting of the data worked out. That much is working wonderfully. However, it immediate turns around and loads the page and sorts and processes the data again. And again. And again. And again. It doesn't actually ever stop loading/processing.
Eventually it's going to sort through a list of pages, but I want to figure out what's going wrong on this particular one before adding that functionality.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Setup();
}

private void Setup()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
    wb.AllowNavigation = true;
    wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_ShipDocumentCompleted);
    wb.Navigate("http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/imo:9268863/");
}

private void wb_ShipDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //  Objects
    WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;
    //  Primitives
    string Document = wb.DocumentText;
    //  Parsing/sorting/DB logic <omitted for length>
}
```

Comment: Are you assigning anything to `wb.DocumentText` later on in `wb_ShipDocumentCompleted`?

Comment: The code you have posted can not result in infinite loop. Post your real code.....

Comment: Szabolcs: No, it's not touched again. Because of the way the website was written, I just converted the page to a string to parse based on what identifying information came before the values I need.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to Your completed event handler:

```
wb.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(null, null);
```

The point being - I'm guessing You have some left overs from previous executions.
or maybe a website is You're downloading has some redirects
or maybe it's trying to popup another site or smth..